# Matplotlib: xmax value and grid line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot made with Matplotlib.

X-values - time

Y-values - numeric data

Data starts at 14:00 and ends at 15:00. But the last data point on the plot **is not on 15:00 grid line.**

I tried to use set_xlim() but this way took away left and right margins.
I need to fit the plot to the grid lines AND I need to have left and right margins.

**Is there a way to do that?**

Here is my code and a couple of pictures:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as pltdates
import os

timeValues = [737327.58333333, 737327.58402778, 737327.58472222, 737327.58541667, 737327.58611111, 737327.58680556, 737327.5875, 737327.58819444, 737327.58888889, 737327.58958333, 737327.59027778, 737327.59097222, 737327.59166667, 737327.59236111, 737327.59305556, 737327.59375, 737327.59444444, 737327.59513889, 737327.59583333, 737327.59652778, 737327.59722222, 737327.59791667, 737327.59861111, 737327.59930556, 737327.6, 737327.60069444, 737327.60138889, 737327.60208333, 737327.60277778, 737327.60347222, 737327.60416667, 737327.60486111, 737327.60555556, 737327.60625, 737327.60694444, 737327.60763889, 737327.60833333, 737327.60902778, 737327.60972222, 737327.61041667, 737327.61111111, 737327.61180556, 737327.6125, 737327.61319444, 737327.61388889, 737327.61458333, 737327.61527778, 737327.61597222, 737327.61666667, 737327.61736111, 737327.61805556, 737327.61875, 737327.61944444, 737327.62013889, 737327.62083333, 737327.62152778, 737327.62222222, 737327.62291667, 737327.62361111, 737327.62430556]
values = [74.3635, 74.3635, 74.3635, 74.3635, 74.3635, 74.3584, 74.3584, 74.3584, 74.3584, 74.3584, 74.3584, 74.3584, 74.3584, 74.3584, 74.3584, 74.3593, 74.3593, 74.3593, 74.3593, 74.3593, 74.3593, 74.3593, 74.3593, 74.3593, 74.3593, 74.3591, 74.3591, 74.3591, 74.3591, 74.3591, 74.3591, 74.3591, 74.3591, 74.3591, 74.3591, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3608, 74.3583, 74.3583, 74.3583, 74.3583]

myFmt = pltdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
xlocator = pltdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55], interval=1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.grid(True, color='#efefef')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(xlocator)

# ax.set_xlim(min(timeValues), max(timeValues))
# ax.set_xbound(min(timeValues), max(timeValues))
# ax.margins(1, 1)

ax.plot(timeValues, values, color='green', linewidth=0.7)
ax.scatter(timeValues, values, c='green')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.95, bottom=0.05, left=0.05, right=0.95, hspace=0.2)

fileName = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'report.pdf')
plt.savefig(fileName, dpi=150)
plt.close()
```

[image: The Plot]

[image: The Problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your timeValues-array contains but I think it's a number of days? In that case the last value in your timeValues array corresponds to 14:59:00 instead of 15:00:00:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> last_timeValue = 737327.62430556
>>> dayFraction =         0.62430556
>>> seconds = dayFraction * 60 * 60 * 24  # dayFraction * seconds in day
>>> print datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds)
1970-01-01 14:59:00.000384
```